# CiviCRM Extension: SMS Inbox Requirements

Tags: sms

Does anyone have any prototype/working SMS inbox functionality?

What would you ideally like to see in an SMS inbox?

So far I've:

Mark message as read.
Attach SMS to contact.

Other suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If you remember, we almost did, but we'd have had to pay for the tagged VMN service (a bit like extension numbers). That or have more than one line. Otherwise if you're dealing with inbound SMS, you know who it's from, but not who it's to, because you only have one line.

Mark as read could be either the status, or a custom field on the activity.

Comment: Hi DaveFF,

In this case knowing which staff member it's to is less important - the organisation received the message is what matters.We know which line it came in on. That will suffice.